# ios 14 ,swipe up to go Home, automatically open picture in picture failed

Tags: ios, ios14

iOS 14 uses a custom player, and when you enter the background, it will not automatically start picture in picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t activate PiP mode during app enters background mode.

See docs -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller

> Picture in Picture (PiP) is a user feature that Apple intends to always be under user control. Invoke PiP only in response to a user’s explicit request to do so. If an app invokes PiP in a way that isn’t under the immediate direction of the user, the App Store review team will reject it.

So try to use a UI button to activate PiP mode.